# Is '.env.' file is secure to store sensitive keys in production?

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-security, dotenv, flutter-secure-storage

I am developing a Flutter mobile and web app, using Firebase as a database. I want to store Firebase's all keys like the API key, app ID, project ID, etc... securely. I am using '.env'. file to store them. But is it safe in production?

Comment: Where is the file located? On your local machine? On some image in cloud? In the repo?

Comment: In my local machine @MarekPuchalski

Answer (score 0):

One thing i should add is if you are using github as your version control, then don't forget to add your .env file to the .gitignore file.

Comment: Yes, it is added but is it safe in production? Can I publish my web app?